# NodeJS callback not printing output when it is success

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, telnet

I have written following code which uses nodejs callback.
It correctly prints `error` when there is no telnet connection.

However, it is not printing `Success!` when telnet is performed successfully

When I manually perform `telnet linux003 4102` I see a blank screen. Blank screen means telnet is connected successfully

```
var abc = require("expect-telnet");
abc("linux003:4102", 
function(err) {
  if (err) { 
    console.error(err);
  }
  else {
    console.log('Success!');
  }
});
```

Comment: When you see a blank screen means its not connected???

Comment: blank screen means it is connected

Answer (score 0):

according to expect-telnet doc, call back is only called when an error happens.

Comment: How to print `Success!`? what changes do I need to make in my code to perform that

Comment: @meallhour try "telnet-client" it returns promise also you can use async awit it will throw an error or sucess
https://www.npmjs.com/package/telnet-client

Comment: I am trying to use `telnet-client`. can you help resolve the error faced there? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58212553/socket-not-writable-while-using-telnet-client

Answer (score 0):

As per `expect-telnet`, the callback is called only when there will be an error.
So, in following

```
var abc = require("expect-telnet");
abc("linux003:4102", 
function(err) {
  if (err) { 
    console.error(err);
  }
  else {
    console.log('Success!');
  }
});
```

the callback will only be called if there is an error. So `Success!` will not be printed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be able to leverage the [`out` property](https://github.com/silverwind/expect-telnet#expect-step-object) in the expect step object:

> `out` *function*: Output function, receives the output since the previous step.

```js
const et = require("expect-telnet");

et("linux003:4102", [
  {
    expect: "some expected text", 
    out(output) {
      console.log("Success");
    }, 
    send: "exit\r"
}
], (err) => {
  if (err) console.error(err);
});
```

That being said, this package is no longer being maintained (see [here](https://github.com/silverwind/expect-telnet#expect-step-object)), and the author recommends another package that looks like it would allow you to do this [here](https://github.com/silverwind/expect-telnet/issues/9#issuecomment-371768504)).

Comment: It is still not displaying the `Success` message.  I am trying to use `telnet-client`. can you help resolve the error faced there? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58212553/socket-not-writable-while-using-telnet-client