# Socket not writable while using `telnet-client`

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, telnet

I am using the following code to perform telnet using NodeJS but it is throwing `socket not writable` error

```
'use strict'

const Telnet = require('telnet-client')

async function run() {
  let connection = new Telnet()

  let params = {
    host: 'linux0203',
    port: 2345,
    shellPrompt: '/ # ',
    timeout: 1500
  }

  try {
    await connection.connect(params)
  } catch(error) {
    // handle the throw (timeout)
  }

  let res = await connection.exec('uptime')
  console.log('async result:', res)
}

run()
```

Error:

```
(node:23452) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: socket not writable
    at Promise (\home\user1\project\\node_modules\telnet-client\lib\index.js:147:23)
```

Comment: To what kind of server do you want to connect to? Is it a telnet server or something else? Also please post: `telnet linux0203 2345`

Comment: As i mentioned in my question, telnet server is working. `telnet linux0203 2345` says connecting and then a blank screen pops up - which means connected successfuly